# Android Lolipop 5.0 WebViewでgetUserMediaを使用したい

Tags: android

AndroidのWebViewでgetUserMediaを使用してウェブカメラを起動したいです。
以下のコードを書いていますが、errorCallbackが呼ばれてしまいます。

解決策を教えてほしいです。

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

// Settings
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), “Android”);

// Set a web view client and a chrome client
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  // Need to accept permissions to use the camera and audio
  @Override
  public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, “onPermissionRequest”);
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if(request.getOrigin().toString().equals(LOCAL_FILE)) {
          request.grant(request.getResources());
        } 
        else {
            request.deny();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
// Load the local HTML file into the webview
myWebView.loadUrl(LOCAL_FILE);
```

[XML]

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/webview" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[permissions]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

[JavaScript]

```
 var constraints = {video: true, audio: true};
 var localStream = null;
 function init() {
    console.log(‘Getting user media with constraints’, constraints);
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMediaSuccess, handleUserMediaError);
 };

 function handleUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
    console.log(‘[+] Successfully got local video stream!’);
    attachMediaStream = function(element, stream) {
          element.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    };
    attachMediaStream(document.getElementById(“localVideo”), stream);
 };

 function handleUserMediaError(error) {
    alert("[!] getUserMedia error: " + error);
    //[object NavigatorUserMediaError]
 };

 window.onload = function() {
    init();
 };
```

追記:alertの出力が間違っていました。

errorCallbackで得られる値は[object NavigatorUserMediaError]になります。
objectのnameは"PermissionDeniedError"となっています。

Comment: `handleUserMediaError` に渡された `error` の値は何になっていますか？

Comment: alertの出力が間違っていました。[object NavigatorUserMediaError]です。

Answer (score 0):

WebChromeClient.onPermissionRequestを実装するとできると思います。